# Rename [vampire-bloodlines] and [vampire-redemption] following the tag limit increase

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Since tag length limit has been increased to 35 characters, I suggest to rename [vampire-bloodlines](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-bloodlines) to [vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines) (33 characters).

The other tag, [vampire-redemption](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-redemption), could follow the same fate and become [vampire-the-masquerade-redemption](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-the-masquerade-redemption) (also 33 chars).

The old tags I propose to keep as tag synonyms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done.

- [vampire-bloodlines](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-bloodlines) -> [vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines)
- [vampire-redemption](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-redemption) -> [vampire-the-masquerade-redemption](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-the-masquerade-redemption)